# ASP.NET Cookies duplicated for subdomain

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication, .aspxauth

I have two asp.net sites. one is like domain.com and the second is sub.domain.com. The domain.com sets aspxauth cookies on login and removes it (via expiration date in the past) on logout. The cookie domain is ".domain.com" so it's available on both side. sub.domain.com is passive about cookies and just tries to read the cookies and authenticate user if cookie was found.

The problem. After some period of time the browser gets the second ASPXAuth cookies with the "domain.com" (without ".") domain - so log out doesn't work since only first (".domain.com") cookie is removed.

Config is

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2880" domain=".domain.com"/>
</authentication>
```

Set cookie

```
public static void SetAuthCookie(IUserPrincipal principal, DateTime expiration)
    {
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, principal.Identity.Name, DateTime.Now, expiration, false,
            principal.SessionId, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        if (response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
        }

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket)
        {
            Expires = expiration,
            Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
        };
        response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
    }
```

Remove cookie

```
 public static void SignOut()
    {
        SetContextPrincipal(null);
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
```

Comment: Check if you have `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` somewhere in your code. I've seen dozens of similar issues and it always was some rarely used path in the code that added the cookie on its own.

Comment: Don't have FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage in our code